# Web Api exclude message handler in route

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a message handler, and this is called for every request. All works fine. However, I would like to have a controller that doesn't use the message handler.

Is there a way to exclude the message handler from being called in a particular route?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the override inside of:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "RouteWithHandler",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: null,
        handler: new MyMessageHandler() 
    );
```

and then adding a route without the handler.

Comment: Would not work. Global message handlers are executed even if there are per-route message handlers, and they are executed **before** it reaches `HttpRoutingDispatcher` (and the route specific handlers). [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers)